# Why FtpWebRequest is adding the user login as part of the target dataset?

Tags: c#, ftp, mainframe, ftpwebrequest

I recently converted a Windows cmd to `FtpWebRequest` using C# to upload file to an IBM mainframe dataset. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357969/).

Running both I found they upload to different dataset when they should be exactly alike, `FtpWebRequest` is adding the user login info to the dataset.

The code on cmd uploads the file to: `'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC'` dataset and the C# code upload the file to: `USERME.ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC`. I need the C# code to upload to the dataset: `ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC`. I know that they are uploading to different dataset because after uploading the file using C# if I use a cmd to get the file like:

```
get 'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC' examplefile`
```

does not give me anything but if I do it like this:

```
get 'USERME.ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC' examplefile`
```

I got the file. What I'm missing here?

Here is the Windows cmd:

```
Open abc.wyx.state.aa.bb
User
Pass
lcd c:\Transfer>
Put examplefile 'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC'
close
bye
```

Here C# using `FtpWebRequest`

```
string ftpfullpath = @"ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC'";            
try
{

    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = false;  //Use ascii.              

    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(source);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();

    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ftpstream.Close();
}
```

Here is the network.log from C#:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpWebRequest#53578024::.ctor(ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpWebRequest#53578024::GetRequestStream(Method=STOR.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] RAS supported: True
System.Net Error: 0 : [8736] Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri 'ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC'. Error code: 12180.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Created connection from 10.11.12.134:56789 to 123.456.78.90:12.
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] Associating FtpWebRequest#53578024 with FtpControlStream#38366678
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [220-FTP 17:02:28 on 2015-05-26.
220-                          Warning!
220 Connection will close if idle for more than 5 minutes.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Sending command [USER USERME]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [331 Send password please.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Sending command [PASS ********]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [230 USERME is logged on.  Working directory is "USERME.".]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Sending command [OPTS utf8 on]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [501 command OPTS aborted -- no options supported for utf8]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Sending command [PWD]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [257 "'USERME.'" is working directory.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Sending command [TYPE A]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [200 Representation type is Ascii NonPrint]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Sending command [PASV]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [227 Entering Passive Mode (204,122,60,60,157,239)]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Sending command [STOR ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [125 Storing data set USERME.ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpControlStream#38366678 - Received response [250 Transfer completed successfully.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [8736] FtpWebRequest#53578024::(Releasing FTP connection#38366678.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and should work.

---

When I use your code, my log shows:

```
FtpWebRequest#7746814::.ctor(ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC')
```

Note the quotes. But they are missing in your log:

```
FtpWebRequest#53578024::.ctor(ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC)
```

Are you really showing us your exact code and matching log file?

---

The `WebRequest.Create` creates an `Uri` class our of the URI string and calls `.ToString()` on that to log it.

And obviously the

```
new Uri(@"ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC'").ToString()
```

is:

```
ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC'
```

What does it return for you?

---

Note all that is happening well before it connects to the server. So there's no space for server-specific behavior.

---

Also, what version of .NET framework are you using? In case this behavior has changed.

Comment: It was an issue with the quotes, like @MartinPrikryl suggest I was not showing the exact code and matching log file. for testing I was using: `string ftpfullpath = @"ftp://abc.wyx.state.aa.bb/'ABCD.AA.C58FC.ABC1FD.ZP3ABC'";` but on production I was building the the path dynamic like this: `string ftpfullpath = @"ftp://" + HostName + "/" + target;`. the correct one is `string ftpfullpath = @"ftp://" + HostName + "/'" + target +"'";`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Still learning how the acceptance and upvote works.

Answer (score 3):

Bound your file-name from the C# by single quotes.

I know why it happens generally (because TSO/ISPF will pre-prend a created file-name with the userid) but I don't know why it should happen in your case (unless the C# stuff thinks it is necessary) but that's the way around it.

OK, I see that you are doing that (probably) already, which seems to imply that the C# is stripping them off. So you need to "protect" the apparent single- quotes that you are giving.

Some main shots:

```
"'abcd.efg.hij'"
"''abcd.efg.hij''"
''abcd.efg.hij''
```

You get the idea.

Is there documentation of the C# stuff?