# Trying to download from IBM mainframe using C#

Tags: c#, ftp, mainframe, ftpwebrequest

I found a Windows command-line snippet to download a file from an IBM Z/OS mainframe that works and now I would like to replicate this code using C# and .NET. Here are the two Windows command-line files:

BatchFtp.bat:

```
rem 999.999.99.99 is mainframe IP Address
ftp -s:C:\scripts\script.txt 999.999.99.99
pause
```

C:\scripts\script.txt:

```
myid
MyPwd
cd ..
get "GIO.END.GPROD.PROC(MYDSNAME)" "c:\scripts\GIO.END.GPROD.PROC(MYDSNAME).txt"
quit
```

I've tried several C# FTP open source examples including the following but I get errors with all of them.

For example, when executing the following code, I get an error

> The remote server returned an error: (425) Can't open data connection.

When executing this line:

```
ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Here's the code that I execute:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* Download a File */
    Ftp ftpClient = new Ftp("999.999.99.99", "MyUserIdHere", "MypasswordHere");

    ftpClient.download(@"GIO.END.GPROD.PROC(DsNmHere)", @"'c:\junk\GIO.END.GPROD.PROC(DsNmHere).txt'");
}

class Ftp
{
    private string host = null;
    private string user = null;
    private string pass = null;
    private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
    private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
    private Stream ftpStream = null;
    private int bufferSize = 2048;

    /* Construct Object */

    public Ftp(string hostIP, string userName, string password)
    {
        host = hostIP; 
        user = userName; 
        pass = password;
    }

    /* Download File */
    public void download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            /* Create an FTP Request */

            string fullPath = @"ftp://" + this.host + "/'" + remoteFile + "'";

            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create(fullPath);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            /* When in doubt, use these options */
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse) ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            /* Open a File Stream to Write the Downloaded File */
            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
            /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            /* Download the File by Writing the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
            try
            {
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I am assuming that my URL must be constructed wrong. Once connected, how do I handle the `cd` (Change Directory) command found in the working batch file example?

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Look to the right of your question, underneath "related" in the side-bar. Anything there of any use?

Comment: I've been looking at a lot of posts, including those. Nothing yet that worked. Thanks...

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/q/30357969/1927206. Search box at the top right, put `[mainfame] and [c#] and [ftp]`. It's come up in two or three ways over the last few months. Make sure you look in recent order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ftp.exe` scripts uses the active FTP mode. (The `ftp.exe` supports only the active mode.)

While your C# code uses the passive FTP mode. And there's some problem with it, as the *"Can't open data connection"* message indicates.

Try using the active mode by removing this line:

```
ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
```

Though note that in general the passive mode tends to be less problematic. See [my guide to understand why the passive mode prevails nowadays](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes). But as you prove that the active mode works in your case, stick with that.

---

To answer your other question: There's no way to issue the `cd` command with the `FtpWebRequest`. Just use a full path instead:

```
ftp://host/../remotefile
```

The `../` is there instead of the `cd ..`

For a general information about working with paths with the `FtpWebRequest` against the IBM mainframe FTP server, see:
[Use C# to FTP file to mainframe including dataset - Translate FTP script to FtpWebRequest code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30357969/850848)

Comment: I removed the quotes, which I added because of an post that I saw. I chanegd UsePassive to true and now I am getting the error 
"Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)." This looks like progress to me. But I know that the file exists and that I have access, because the DOS version works, so the fullPath must not be correct. Thanks!

Comment: What about `ftp://host/../GIO.END.GPROD.PROC(MYDSNAME)` (the `/../` is there for the `cd ..`)

Comment: You're who I was hoping to see :-)

Comment: @Martin, nice suggestions (the "..") but I got the same error. Thanks.

Comment: I re-added the single quotes around the file name and it worked! ftp://99.99.999.9/../'GIO.END.GPROD.PROC(MYDSNNM)' Thank you for your help, I probably wouldn't have otherwise have figured it out.